# separating data from 1 column into 2

Tags: data-cleaning

I have data columns in this format
Ardencaple Mince(SD-818-2146-04)

I want to separated it out into 2 new columns with Name and code. I tried variations of the separate function but couldn't get the desired result. Any suggestions for a quick solution.

this is one variation I tried

separate(site_name, c("site", "site_id"),sep = ("()"))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract()` -- here's some example code

```
library(tidyr)

# example data
df <- data.frame(site_name = c("Ardencaple Mince(SD-818-2146-04)", "Some Site Name(ID-123-456)"))

# extract name and code
df <- df %>%
  extract(site_name, into = c("name", "code"), regex = "(.*)\\((.*)\\)")

# print result
df
```

- will create a new dataframe  with two columns name and code extracted from site_name
- extract() takes the original column name -- a vector of new column names -- and a regex pattern for extracting the name and code values
- The pattern (.*)\((.*)\) matches any character before an opening parentheses ( and extracts it as the name -- matches any characters inside the parentheses and extracts it as the code